# Is there a "Tree Structure Editor" for Lisp?

Tags: tree, editor, lisp, structure

I've heard that S-expressions can be represented as trees; for example `(f 1 (g 2) 3)` as

```
      .
 .  .  .    .
f  1   .      3          [first level]
      g  2               [second level]
```

Is there an editor (preferably free) for editing this kind of structure directly?  This would

1. Avoid "all those parentheses"
2. Exhibit the elegance I've been understanding of lisp.

Answer (score 5):

S-expressions represent a tree, not the other way around.  Your example, formatted with newlines:

```
(f 1
   (g 2)
   3)
```

It represents the following cons tree:

```
    +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+   +---+---+
--->| f | ----->| 1 | ----->| ¦ | ----->| 3 |NIL|
    +---+---+   +---+---+   + ¦ +---+   +---+---+
                              v
                            +---+---+   +---+---+
                            | g | ----->| 2 |NIL|
                            +---+---+   +---+---+
```

This is at the same time the actual abstract syntax tree of the program—something that compilers for other language families have to construct from intricate rules.

For editing, the parentheses are all you and your editor need to operate on the tree level.  In Emacs it is **paredit-mode**, but I guess that other editors have similar utilities or plugins.

Comment: I get how the parentheses are representative of the tree structure; I was just wondering if there was an editor that displays the tree as a diagrammatic tree for the user to edit.  (I'm not sure that the pointers would be user-friendly for such a thing, but I guess it could work.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (and as the Wikipedia article confirms), [structure editing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_editor) was used in [Interlisp-D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlisp-D). I am not aware of any structure editor for Common Lisp widely in use today, but maybe there is something I don't know about. There is an [example](http://www.informatimago.com/develop/lisp/small-cl-pgms/sedit/index.html) on Pascal J. Bourguignon 's site you may want to play around with. (I didn't take a closer look at it) I did, however use something similar for XML in [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) some time ago.

(Also, I don't think the reason Interlisp used this had anything to do with getting rid of the parentheses, and there might be problems with comments, for example.)

Comment: I guess Pascal's program could be useful, if I can figure out how to integrate it into emacs.  It's not quite the tree editor I was looking for, though, so I think I should keep the question open for now.  I confess I don't really understand Interlisp even after some googling; was it an operating system for Lisp Machines?  (Unfortunately, that probably wouldn't help very much! :)

Comment: Yes, Interlisp ran on Lisp Machines and was one of the systems in use before Common Lisp. Common Lisp, however, was more strongly influenced by Maclisp, and the use of structure editors didn't catch on. Even if this doesn't "help very much", it's maybe good to know that structure editing is not a new idea, but was already in use a few decades ago. (I remember discussions about this on c.l.l., so you might want to search for this topic in google groups.)

Comment: If you really want to write an Emacs mode for something like this, maybe you could also consider a mode that just changes the way the code is represented and edited, instead of changing sexps directly, as Pascal's code does. (That's the approach of XML tools like Oxgen) Then you could avoid possible problems with in-code comments, and it would be easier to exchange code with others, who don't use structure editing.

Answer (score 2):

The [ParEdit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) mode for emacs is essentially a structured editor.

Also, in [their paper](https://www.fbi.h-da.de/fileadmin/personal/b.humm/Publikationen/Gomolka_Humm_-_Structure_Editors__Springer_ENASE_.pdf), Gomolka & Humm mention a research prototype extending [CUSP](http://www.sergeykolos.com/cusp/update/) for Eclipse, but I don't know of a downloadable implementation.

Comment: That's infuriating.  Provide complete description of structure editor, including pics, lines of code, survey results, then no hint as to where to get it.  (To be honest I probably wouldn't switch from emacs nowadays, but just the same.)  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Gingko as a Tree Structure editor for lisp]

We're working on letting you [write Lisp with Gingko](http://blog.gingkoapp.com/features/gingko-as-a-lisp-editor) (a general tree structure editor).

The conversion from tree to source is trivial, so really the only thing missing is more depth (Gingko is currently limited to 3 levels).

*[This is still very experimental, so I'd love feedback & input from Lisp experts.]*